# How do I remove this product?

Tags: trigonometry

I have a sine function whose input is $\pi \centerdot z$. Is there a generalization of $sin(-b) = -sin(b)$ that extends to $sin(ab) = a'sin(b)$, such that I could obtain $\pi' sin(z)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $a$ integer you have the Bernoulli-Euler formulas:

$$
\sin ax = \sum_{0\leq j \leq (a-1)/2} (-1)^j \binom{k}{2j+1} (\cos x)^{k-2j-1} (\sin x)^{2j+1},
$$
$$
\cos ax = \sum_{0\leq k \leq a/2} (-1)^j \binom{k}{2j} (\cos x)^{k-2j} (\sin x)^{2j}.
$$

Comment: Not exactly simplification.

Answer (score 0):

No there is none

$\sin$ is defined by $2i \sin z = e^{iz} - e^{-iz}$. If you put $z=ab$ into your exponential, you'll see that no simplification will ensue in general

Unless $k$ is an integer and you get $\sin k\pi = 0$ (but still no general expression for $\sin k x$).

Actually, I'm pretty sure that for almost all $x \in \mathbb R$, $\{ \sin kx \}_k$ is dense in $(-1,1)$, which shows that the terms are "pretty random"

Comment: No z is just a complex number, also whats the long answer?

Comment: There's no long answer ...

Comment: then why did you say "(short answer)"?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen while I do agree this could probably be elaborated it is still a answer.

Comment: It meant it was a short answer, not that it was the short version of a long version ...

Comment: @AlexHalm could you include what to do if z were to be an integer?

Comment: Where are you geting z = ab?

Comment: I meant just replace z by ab formally.

Comment: @AlexHalm still the same based on my above clarification?

Comment: Obviously. What makes you think there's any reason for such thing to happen?

Comment: just in case there was a pi specific thing.

Comment: If that answered your question, consider accepting (green check mark) the answer to be a good MSE citizen